# Unable to cast Generic List to Custom List type

Tags: c#, .net, generics, collections, casting

I have a two classes:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}

public class MyList : List<MyClass>
{
}
```

In other code, I am creating instances of `MyClass` for each record from a DB, and I would like to return them all in a `MyList` instance:

```
var records = _repository.GetRecords();
return (MyList) records.Select(x => x.ConvertTo<MyClass>()).ToList();
```

The code compiles fine but it is throwing a **runtime** `InvalidCastException`:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyClass]' to type 'MyList'.

I don't understand why this error is happening because `MyList` *is* a `List<MyClass>`.

I found some related questions which all talk about covariance. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9022811/346561) was the most similar to my problem but I don't know how to adapt the answer to solve my problem.

**My Question:**
How can I build a `MyList` instance out of the DB records?

I am using C# and .NET 4.0

Comment: `List<MyClass>` isn't **automatically** `MyList` too. You could make a constructor that takes a `List<MyClass>` though.

Comment: A *child* is of its *mother* type, not the reverse. One *mother* may have lots of *children*.

Comment: CA1002:DoNotExposeGenericLists -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182142(v=vs.80).aspx ... Keep this in mind.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Every `MyList` is a `List<MyClass>`, but not every `List<MyClass>` is a `MyList`.  For example, if you had a custom property on `MyList`, Linq's `ToList` method would have no knowledge of it.

You could *create* a new `MyList` by using the `List<T>` copy constructor:

```
return new MyList(records.Select(x => x.ConvertTo<MyClass>()).ToList());
```

**EDIT**

As @ekolis estutely noticed, you need to explicitly "inherit" the `List<T>` copy constructor:

```
public class MyList : List<MyClass>
{
    public MyList(IEnumerable<MyClass> list)
        : base(list)
    {
    }
}
```

I would also step back and see if you really *need* a `MyList` class, or if you can just use `List<MyClass>` (or even just `IEnumerable<MyClass>`).

Comment: Note that you actually need to create this copy constructor; it will not be inherited from List<T>.

Comment: The `MyList` class is serialized to XML. I use it instead of a normal `List<MyClass>` because the latter generates an XML element named "ArrayOfMyClass" and I wanted to be able to control the XML element's name to be something custom, in this case "MyList".

Answer (score 0):

You can cast a derived class to the base class, but you can't do the other way.
If you have this:

```
public class Base {}
public class Derived : Base {}
```

You can cast `Derived` to `Base`, but you can't cast `Base` to `Derived`

```
Base b = (Base)new Derived();
```

will work
but not

```
Derived d = (Derived)new Base();
```

the `Derived` class has potentially more information than the `Base` class, that's why

In your situation @D Stanley gave you the solution